# Determine the exact value of $\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)$ if $\csc(\theta) = 3$ and $(\theta)$ is in Quadrant II.

Tags: trigonometry

> Determine $\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)$ if $\csc(\theta) = 3$ and $\theta$ is in Quadrant II. Leave your answer in exact form.

I am unsure of where to begin with this problem. I cannot use a calculator a step by step to help me learn this type would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\csc \theta = 3$ and $\theta$ is in Quadrant II, you have enough data to draw an accurate diagram of the angle in question.  Just recall the basic definition of $\csc$.  Then, $\sin \theta$ can be solved easily from $\csc \theta$, and the Pythagorean Theorem will let you solve for the third side of the triangle, allowing you to calculate $\cos \theta$.

Comment: How is $\csc\theta$ related to $\sin\theta$?  How do you determine the value of $\cos\theta$ if you know the value of $\sin\theta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a triangle. Opposite side is 1, hypotenuse is 3, adjacent side is  $ 2 \sqrt2$ Find sin,cos.Note the signs $+,-$ respectively.